# Jenkins Dynamic Parameter: SVN revision number as default value

Tags: svn, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I want to fill a default value of a text parameter with current SVN revision number.

I created a **Dynamic Parameter** (Dynamic Parameter Plug-in) with *default value script* that looks like this:

```
def url = "http://192.168.0.1/svn/myproj/trunk"
def user = "username"
def password = "password"

return svnrev = "svn info --username $user --password $password --show-item last-changed-revision $url".execute().text
```

But the parameter textfield is just blank. I'm not very familiar with Groovy.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

the --show-item option was added in SVN 1.9